# /usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libR.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: r, object, aws-lambda

I am getting this error while making an image through docker on lambda.

** [ERROR] OSError: cannot load library '/usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libR.so': /usr/local/lib64/R/lib/libR.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

Docker file:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lts/ubuntu:latest
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN apt-get install -y gcc gfortran build-essential
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev
RUN apt-get install -y zlib1g zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev liblzma-dev libpcre++-dev libpango1.0-dev \
    xorg-dev \
    libreadline-dev
RUN wget -c https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.5.0.tar.gz && tar -xf R-3.5.0.tar.gz
RUN cd R-3.5.0 && ./configure --with-readline=no --with-x=no && make && make install
RUN R -e "install.packages('remotes', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "require(remotes)"
RUN R -e "remotes::install_version('text2vec', version = '0.5.1', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3.8 \
    python3-pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install \
    awslambdaric
RUN ln -s /usr/lib64/R/lib/* /usr/local/lib64/R/lib/
COPY lambda_function.py ./
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/python3", "-m", "awslambdaric" ]
CMD ["lambda_function.lambda_handler"]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Add a flag `--enable-R-shlib` when building R, but maybe it's better to 'stand on the  shoulders of giants' and use https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned2? Here's the script used to build R in that project https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned2/blob/master/scripts/install_R.sh

Comment: Generally `no such file or directory` means the user doesn't have permission to access. `ls -la /usr/local/lib64/R/lib | more` will show the permissions that were likely copied from '/usr/lib64/R/lib' as '/usr/local/lib64/R/lib` is sym linked above (RUN ln -s). `chown` your '/usr/local/lib64/R/lib` to give yourself access. Why R-3.5.0?

Comment: @MartinMorgan didn't work

Comment: We supply a number of version base containers as rocker/r-base that are also the official r-base containers so you could just pull `r-base:3.5.0` (though I haven't gone back as as that but I use them otherwise).  These use the official Debian binary with its proper setup, including a shared libary build.  (And I am maintainer of the binary and these containers.)

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up the first parts of your Dockerfile as

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lts/ubuntu:latest
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        wget \
        software-properties-common \
        gcc gfortran build-essential \
        libcurl4-openssl-dev \
        zlib1g zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev liblzma-dev libpcre++-dev libpango1.0-dev \
        xorg-dev \
        libreadline-dev && \
        apt-get clean && \
        rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN wget -c https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.5.0.tar.gz && \
        tar -xf R-3.5.0.tar.gz && \
        cd R-3.5.0 && \
        ./configure --with-readline=no --with-x=no --enable-R-shlib && \
        make -j && make install
```

Putting all the apt-get into one RUN allows one to clean up by removing apt cache files. Using `make -j` builds R in parallel, which can speed up the build significantly.

I then built it, and launched the resulting image using bash to see that `libR.so` did indeed exist.

```
$ docker build .
...
Successfully built f1d83e97e8ef
$ docker run -it --rm f1d83e97e8ef bash
root@add29666d5d5:/# ls -l /usr/local/lib64/R/lib
total 21984
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 16815248 Sep  5 14:43 libR.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   462896 Sep  5 14:43 libRblas.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5226296 Sep  5 14:43 libRlapack.so
```

`libR.so` exists and permissions (read and execute for all)  are appropriate.

I don't think exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH or creating a symbolic link should be necessary.